# "TypeError is null" conflict js

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I have two plugin, if i use one without the other it works correctly...
But both together doesn't work.

I'm getting this error when i check the console : TypeError: a is null

What's going on ?

thanks.

Header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.list.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    $.list.init();
});
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jcart/js/jcart.js"></script>
```

jquery.list.js :

```
(function($) {
    $.list = {
        file: 'request-list.php',
            setData: 'go',
            id: 'te',
            title: null,

            init: function() {
                $.list.getList();
                $('#te').on('change', function() {
                $.list.setData = 'idte='+$('#te').val();
                $.list.id = 'reg';
                $.list.title = 'regions';
                $.list.getList();
                $('#frn').html('<option value="0">--frni--</option>');

            });
            $('#reg').on('change', function() {
                $.list.setData = 'idreg='+$(this).val();
                $.list.id = 'frn';
                $.list.title = 'Fournisseur';
                $.list.getList();
            });
        },

        getList: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: $.list.file,
                data: $.list.setData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    if (!!$.list.title) {
                        $('select#'+$.list.id).html('');
                        $('#'+$.list.id).append('<option value="0">--'+$.list.title+'--</option>');
                    }
                    $.each(json, function(index, value) {
                        $('#'+$.list.id).append('<option value="'+index+'">'+value+'</option>');
                    });
                    switch ($.list.id) {
                        case 'uni':
                            $.list.setData = 'ecolesd=ok&idcom='+$('#com').val();
                            $.list.id = 'ecolesd';
                            $.list.title = 'Ecole secondaire';
                            $.list.getList();
                            break;
                        case 'ecolesd':
                            $.list.setData = 'ecolepri=ok&idcom='+$('#com').val();
                            $.list.id = 'ecolepri';
                            $.list.title = 'Ecole Primaire';
                            $.list.getList();
                            break;
                    }
}
            });
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Which line does the error point to? In which file? What in your own code triggers the error?

Comment: FWIW, `$(document).ready(function() {  })` and `$(function() {  })` are identical. There's no need to wrap `$.list.init();` inside both of them.

Comment: The error point to jquery-1.7.2.min.js line 2, (function(a,b){function cy(a) etc... I have a dropdown when i click on te i'm getting this error.

Comment: Try removing the duplicate `DOMReady` function.

Comment: BenM => ok i got it, but nothing changed, it still doesn't work correctly. I mean when i click on a "te" i can see the differnet value, it's fine but on my reg nothing happened. Without jcart.js it works ...

Comment: Without this js (jcart.js), my script jquery.list.js works perfectly... what's wrong ?